# IPN is now disabled Need help deciphering the asp code

Tags: asp-classic, paypal-ipn

Paypal has been sending emails warning IPN is failing.

I've not made any changes to my code, and it is really old code.... has been working for 5+ years.... been so long that I've had to do anything on this site.

I searched the server logs for more information... this is what I found repeatedly

```
|35|80040e14|Syntax_error_(missing_operator)_in_query_expression_'OrderID='.
```

I checked the code on the ipn page of the site, and I'm stumped.
Nothing is changed but it stopped working

This is line 34 thru 36 of the code of the ipn page:

```
MM_Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Orders SET txn_id='" & txn_id & "',payment_status='" & payment_status & "' WHERE OrderID=" & Item_number
MM_Cmd.Execute 
end function
```

UPDATE:
Here is the full code that shows Item_number:

```
<%
str = Request.Form & "&cmd=_notify-validate"

' post back to PayPal system to validate
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHttp.Send str

' assign posted variables to local variables
Item_number = Request("item_number")
Payment_status = Request("payment_status")
Txn_id = Request("txn_id")
if (objHttp.status <> 200 ) then
' HTTP error handling
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED") then
if Payment_status = "Completed" then 'only update database if the response text is verified and the payment complete
UpdateOrder
end if
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "INVALID") then
' log for manual investigation
else
' error
end if

set objHttp = nothing

function UpdateOrder
'on error resume next
Set MM_Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
MM_Cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_CharonCart_STRING
MM_Cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Orders SET txn_id='" & txn_id & "',payment_status='" & payment_status & "' WHERE OrderID=" & Item_number
MM_Cmd.Execute 
end function
%>
```

Comment: The error seems to say that Item_number is empty. Can you update your question with more code that shows how Item_number gets its value?

Comment: Thanks Sander_P  ... I've added the code to the original question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your variable Item_number. There's a small chance that if you rewrite the end of your query as

```
... where OrderID=" & Cint(Item_number)
```

then you will solve your problem, however you probably need to look at the code which assigns a value to Item_number